# Connect to SqlServer with socket programming

Tags: c#, c++, sql-server, database, ado.net

I'm wondering if there is a direct way of connecting to SQL Server. In other words, How ADO.NET is connecting to SQL Server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For academic exercise kind of work the TDS protocol is described at [Tabular Data Stream Protocol Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd304523%28v=prot.13%29.aspx) and there is a free implementation at [FreeTDS](http://www.freetds.org/). Do you have any real motive to re-invent the wheel?